# How to preferentially mark websites untrusted with Noscript?

Tags: facebook, firefox, browser-addons

For example, if I want to disable Facebook when I enter website X, I can mark Facebook untrusted there. However, the effect is universal; that is when I visit Facebook or website Y, I have to mark it back as trusted.
What can I do so that  the effect is only on some specific websites of my choice? I use [Noscript](http://noscript.net/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you can do this with ABE in noscript. There is [an example](http://noscript.net/faq#qa5_4) set out for akamai.net in the noscript FAQ.

Essentially you need to get to the ABE interface in the Advanced tab of noscript option

[image: ABE section of the noscript options]

and in there you want to enter something like

```
Site .facebook.com
Accept INCLUSION from SELF++
Accept INCLUSION from .X.com
Deny
```

That way Facebook is allowed with X.com, and when you visit Facebook normally, but denied for all other sites.

Comment: Yeah, I had to try many things until it worked. For example the pdf file for ABE rules does not exist.

Comment: What did you do that eventually worked?

Comment: It would take me too much time to check if all the rules I put are necessary, but it's a variation of what you wrote. Basically I added more rules.

Comment: @Theta30 - no probs :) glad to have helped a little.